# Why doesn't this image_tag work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get this to work.

```
<%= image_tag('http://img.youtube.com/vi/<%= @video_tag %>/hqdefault.jpg') %>
```

It works with just the link itself but the image_tag to display it is causing the following error:

**Error:**

```
Showing /Users/maine/Downloads/leap_stage_v2/leap_stage_v2/app/views/songs/show.html.erb where line #19 raised:

/Users/maine/Downloads/leap_stage_v2/leap_stage_v2/app/views/songs/show.html.erb:19: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ')'
...er.safe_append='/hqdefault.jpg\') %>
...                               ^
/Users/maine/Downloads/leap_stage_v2/leap_stage_v2/app/views/songs/show.html.erb:68: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
/Users/maine/Downloads/leap_stage_v2/leap_stage_v2/app/views/songs/show.html.erb:70: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
Extracted source (around line #19):


   http://img.youtube.com/vi/<%= @video_tag %>/hqdefault.jpg

   <%= image_tag('http://img.youtube.com/vi/<%= @video_tag %>/hqdefault.jpg') %>


    <div class="videos">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest the `<%` tags.  Assuming `@video_tag` is a string, you can do the following to achieve what you want:

```
<%= image_tag("http://img.youtube.com/vi/#{@video_tag}/hqdefault.jpg") %>
```